# Is freebsd C crypt() threadsafe?

Tags: c, multithreading, freebsd, crypt

When I read

> BUGS
>
> ```
>  The crypt() function returns a pointer to static data, and subsequent
>  calls to crypt() will modify the same data.  Likewise, crypt_set_format()
>  modifies static data.
> ```

from: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crypt&sektion=3

I was scared about I had to lock each time I'm calling `crypt()` but on this source 
(http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/crypt.html)

I read:

> The crypt() function need not be reentrant. A function that is not required to be reentrant is not required to be thread-safe.

What sounds not plausible to me.

I mean how can I generate a reproduceable hash, If another thread is just putting values in the flow, which aren't belonging together?

Is it true, that this function doesn't need to be thread safe to work correctly?

Comment: no, it's not threadsafe. Since it's using the SAME internal static data structure, two threads calling crypt() at the same time will start trashing each other's data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not thread-safe. The quote you found is simply stating that the implementers weren't required to make the function thread-safe, therefore it isn't. If you call it simultaneously from multiple threads, bad things will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just responding to this old post to let you know: FreeBSD HEAD (read: 12.0) will provide a copy of `crypt_r()` that is thread-safe. Enjoy!

[FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crypt_r&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12-current&arch=default&format=html)

Comment: could you elaborate this a bit further please. sounds itneresting but I don't get what you are trying to tell me at all.

Comment: I'm the person who added this function to FreeBSD. I did some Googling and stumbled upon this post, specifically referring to FreeBSD (the man page link). I thought I'd post this comment to keep others informed who stumble upon this post.

Comment: Ah, indeed! thats perfect :) If you could comment the direct link to the man page so I will edit it into your post or you can do it your self if you want, that answer would indeed be a big contribution :)